# How can I determine amount of constructor parameters for a generic type using reflections in java?

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I need to determine how many arguments a constructor accepts during runtime in a generic method. I know every type T extends the same baseclass and they only have one constructor each, but they take different amount of parameters.

```
public T someMethod() {
    // get amount of parameters T constructor takes
}
```

Is there a simple way of achieving this?

Comment: That information won't be available at runtime, and you can't use `T` as a constructor. What are you trying to accomplish? Reflection is most likely unnecessary.

Comment: basically I'm trying to figure out a way to create an object of type T to return from this method

Comment: I'm not sure this is a hard no. Not enough information was given. Show the whole class, and _maybe_.

Comment: @Jacco Then it can be assumed you know what type T is at runtime, correct? If so, follow the example in the answer and pass in a `Class<T>`. Though I'm guessing there's a better way to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider correct, I'm sure there are plenty of better ways to achieve it, but this is what I came up with. Currently attemting to pass Class<T> and it seems to be working as intended.

Comment: Who guarantees that `T` has constructors at all?

Comment: @Holger someMethod() is called from a class that has a generic parameter <T extends Entity>, Entity has a constructor so I guess that guarantees atleast one.

Comment: I can declare an arbitrary method like `<X extends Entity&Runnable> void foo() { }` and call your `someMethod()` from within `foo()` using `X` as type argument for `T` as it fulfills the constraint. The caller of `foo()` doesn’t even have to specify an actual type for `X` at all. Now, where’s the constructor?

Answer (score 2):

No. Due to [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), there is no way to find out anything about `T` from a method with that signature.

If you change the method to accept a *type token*, then yes:

```
public T someMethod(Class<T> clazz) {
    // eg:
    Constructor<?>[] constructors = clazz.getConstructors();
    // eg:
    constructors[i].getParameterTypes();
}
```